# Find an initial condition for the ODE $xy'+3y=6x^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find an initial condition of the form

$$y(x_0)=y_0$$

for the ODE

$$xy'+3y=6x^3$$

so that the solution is

$$ y=x^3-\frac{1}{x^3}$$

I found that the general solution to the ODE is

$$y=x^3+\frac{C}{x^3}$$

So, how should I proceed to find $C$?

Comment: Plug in the initial condition.

Comment: $$y_0 =(x_0)^3+\frac{C}{x_0)^3$$ but how am I going to solve C?

Comment: Observe $y_0 -x_0^3 = C/x_0^3$.

Comment: After rearranging, I found out the solution as shown below... but I don't understand how it turns out $$ (y_0-x_0^3)(x_0)^3=-1$$

Comment: Choose $y(1) = 0$ as your initial condition.

Comment: thank you! I didn't realize I have to choose own value! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $y(x_0)=y_0$ and $y=x^3+\frac{C}{x^3}$, plugging the initial condition yields to
$$y_0=y(x_0)=x_0^3+\frac{C}{x_0^3}.$$
From this,
$$C=(y_0-x_0^3)\;x_0^3.$$
Then, the solution of your ODE is
$$y=x^3+\frac{(y_0-x_0^3)\;x_0^3}{x^3}.$$

Comment: I get there, but how can the solution turns out $$y=x^3-\frac{1}{x^3}$$

Comment: @user118035 That depends on the initial condition. You should have for that $y(1)=0$.

Comment: thank you! now I only understand what the question is asking for

Answer (score 1):

You have found the general solution. That is great!

Now you want to find the initial condition such that the constant, C, in the solution = -1.

Your general solution has the form; y(x) = $x^3$ + $\frac{C}{x^3}$

If we consider the form of the initial condition equated as the form of the general solution;

y($x_0$) = $x_0^3$ + $\frac{C}{x_0^3}$ = $y_0$

We want to find $x_0$ and $y_0$ such that the above equation solves C = -1, by inspection (not always easy) we may choose $y_0$ = 0 and $x_0$ = 1, such that:

y($x_0$ = 1) = 1 + C = 0 = $y_0$ $=>$ C = -1

Hence giving your solution the form:

y(x) = $x^3$ - $\frac{1}{x^3}$

In this particular problem we were asked to solve one equation in one unknown, if we had more than one constant we would have to find additional initial conditions, such as an initial condition on some boundary or on the derivative of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You found that the given function is actually an element of the solution family. Now you have to just pick some $x_0$ and insert into the given function.
\begin{array}{c|c}
x_0&y_0=y(x_0)=x_0^3-\frac1{x_0^3}\\\hline
1&0\\
2&8-\frac18=7+\frac78=\frac{63}{8}\\
\frac12&\frac18-8=-\frac{63}{8}
\end{array}
etc.